# Segmentaiton fault when function is called to input a double into a member of a array, previous input works

Tags: c

For a class assignment in C, I was tasked with writing a program that creates a struct with 4 members, first name, last name, hours, and payrate, after its created, it inputs the user to input the 4 members 3 times, so we have 3 employees. when the program is run, I can input the first and last and hours of the first employee but when it comes to input for the payrate this causes a segmentation fault. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct employee
{
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    double hours;
    double payrate;
};

typedef struct employee emp; 

int main(void)
{
    system("clear");

    emp emp[SIZE];

    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
    {
        input(&emp[counter]);
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
    {
        output(emp[counter]);
    }       

    printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s", "First", "Last", "Hours", "Rate");
    puts("------------------------");

    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d %d \n", emp[30].first, emp[30].last, emp[10].hours, emp[10].payrate);
    }

    return 0;
}

void output(struct employee emp)
{
    printf("First: %s \n", emp.first);
    printf("Last: %s \n", emp.last);
    printf("Hours: %d \n", emp.hours);
    printf("Payrate: %d \n", emp.payrate);
    puts("********************************");
}

void input(emp * ptr)
{
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->first);

    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->last);

    printf("Enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%d", ptr->hours);

    printf("Enter payrate: ");
    scanf("%d", ptr->payrate);

    puts("********************************");
}
```

Edit#1 I edited some code and it works until the part of the table, it now works but gives out a 0.0000 in the first two colums of the table, here the edited code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct employee
{
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    double hours;
    double payrate;
};

typedef struct employee emp; 

int main(void)
{
    system("clear");

    emp emp[SIZE];

    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        input(&emp[counter]);
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        output(emp[counter]);
    }       

    printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s", "First", "Last", "Hours", "Rate");
    puts("\n ------------------------");

    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %lf %lf \n", emp[30].first, emp[30].last, emp[10].hours, emp[10].payrate);
    }

    return 0;
}

void output(struct employee emp)
{
    printf("First: %s \n", emp.first);
    printf("Last: %s \n", emp.last);
    printf("Hours: %f \n", emp.hours);
    printf("Payrate: %f \n", emp.payrate);
    puts("********************************");
}

void input(emp * ptr)
{
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->first);

    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->last);

    printf("Enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ptr->hours);

    printf("Enter payrate: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ptr->payrate);

    puts("********************************");
}
```

Comment: `"%d"` is for INTEGERS, not DOUBLES. Use `"%lf"` for the `double` values in `input()`. See [man 3 scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) The same goes for `output()`, but you can simply use `"%f"` there. Good job on defining the constant with `#define SIZE 3` -- bad job for not using it throughout your code `:)`

Comment: also, you are missing the address-of operator for `ptr->hours` and `ptr->playrate`.

Comment: I would recommend to use `%i` instead of `%d` for `int`s , so that you remember easier the types: i-int f-float u-unsigned and their length modifiers when needed.

Comment: Don't create a variable with the same name as a type: `emp emp[SIZE];`. This is insane (I would have to check if it is valid, but I don't think so). You can do `emp_t emp[SIZE];`.  Or even better, don't typedef at all, and use `struct employee`

Comment: `printf("%s %s %lf %lf \n", emp[30].first, emp[30].last, emp[10].hours, emp[10].payrate);` access the elements indexed 30 and 10 in an array with only 3 elements.

Comment: Why do you use `struct employee` in `output()` but `emp` in `input()`? You should at least be consistent.

Comment: You don't declare the funcions before `main()`. Does this code even compile?  Use `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra` to compile and you will avoid the old implicit declarations and see many errors.

Comment: Edit the question only to improve it.  Avoid adding further questions - especially after an answer has already been given and accepted.  If you have a new question, post a new question;  SO is not a discussion forum.  Apart from that your output loop prints elements from a single out-of-bounds index.  You need `emp[counter].first` etc.

Comment: Although in `printf` `%f` and `%lf` behave both as `double` because of how `printf` works, I would still use `%lf` if you mean `double` and `%f` if you mean `float`. That way you will always know the difference and won't make that error again in `scanf` where it does matter.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", ptr->first);` and similar statements: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Note: it returns the number of successful input format specifier conversions -- in this case '1'   2) when using the input format specifers : '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because these format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also assures no buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that the second argument to scanf should be a pointer.  In the case of your strings, they are arrays and basically treated as pointers anyway so they work fine.  You need to use the & operator to give it the address of the doubles.  The next problem is that the conversion specifier "%d" is for signed integer conversion.  For a double, use "%lf" since a double is a long float.

Example:

```
scanf("%lf", &ptr->hours);
```